# Displaying a default image using props

Tags: reactjs, api, react-props

hello I want to display a default image i have if the path to the poster is set to null in the api database

```
 img={data.poster_path ? data.poster_path : { notFound }}
```

is there a way to do that within the prop itself?
data is the state and posterpath is supposed to be the path  to the image itself. notFound is my default image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass it as prop and add a conditional statement where *img* is being used.

Pass the props as

```
 img={data.poster_path}
```

And in the child component use it conditionally as:

```
{props.img ? <img src={props.img}/> : "Not Found" }
```